# How to apply the same arguments to a list of function calls in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Suppose I want to apply the parameter p1 and p2 to a list of function calls:

```
(defn some-func []
    (let [p1 a p2 b]
    (f1 p1 p2)
    (f2 p1 p2)
    (f3 p1 p2)
...
))
```

What's a good and concise way of doing this?

Comment: It would be great if you accepted some of the answers to your questions.

Comment: Do you want to apply those functions just for "side effects" or you want to use their return values?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want just side-effects, I'd use `doseq` to force the calls;
iterate the functions you want to call.  e.g.

```
user=> (doseq [f [println println println]] (f 1))
1
1
1
nil
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to review [the Clojure CheatSheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet).  [The function `juxt`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/juxt) can do what you want.

Beware, though, `juxt` is somewhat obscure and can make it hard to read your code.

Comment: juxt returns a vector. What I really want is these function calls in a sequence. I tried (lazy-seq (juxt...)), but it says "Can't convert lazyseq to IFn".

Comment: i.e., how do I convert the vec to IFn?

Comment: Read the docs on the 2 links above, esp the 2nd one to clojuredocs.org

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` or `map`, both of which return a `clojure.lang.LazySeq`. Small working example:

```
(defn f1 [x y] (+ x y))
(defn f2 [x y] (- x y))
(defn f3 [x y] (* x 1))

;; Method 1 - for
(for [f [f1 f2 f3]]
  (f 10 5))
;; => (15 5 50)

;; Method 2 - map
(map #(% 10 5) [f1 f2 f3])
;; => (15 5 50)
```